# I am having an issue when migrating using postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

migration 1

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS RecipeCategory;
CREATE TYPE RecipeCategory AS ENUM (
    'Vegetarian',
    'Breakfast',
    'Dinner',
    'Snacks',
    'Sides',
    'Desserts',
    'Soups'
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipe_table (
    recipe_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    recipe_name TEXT not NULL,
    recipe_preptime TEXT,
    recipe_ingredients TEXT NOT NULL,
    recipe_instructions TEXT NOT NULL,
    category RecipeCategory NOT NULL
);
```

migration 2

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY key generated by default AS IDENTITY,
    fullName TEXT NOT NULL,
    username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password TEXT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE recipe_table
ADD COLUMN 
usename INTEGER REFERENCES user_table(user_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Does not show any error in stack trace and says it is created but does not populate into DBeaver.

Comment: Your code [runs fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e3221ab0fb622f644f79a8ec9069b5eb). Note that it is meant to *create* tables, not to populate them.

Comment: You don't say how  or with what the migration is being done. In any case I do not see a `COMMIT`. If that is not being done then the above will not survive the session is was run in and other sessions/clients will not see it.

Comment: I think that I worded it wrong it doesn't create the user table in DBeaver.  The table isn't seeded but it doesn't actually create the table either.  I am doing the migration with a create.sql file and an undo.sql for each. inside of my server for the app I am creating.